# Is there is way to importhtml table and skip repeat column headers?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, unique, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from ESPN that is in a table format but the table repeats headers throughout the table and I want to skip them if possible.

http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/team/_/stat/scoring/year/2019/seasontype/2

I want it to just import this row once at the very top and not repeat! Is this possible?

```
RK  TEAM    GP  G   GA  GF/G    GA/G    DIFF    SF/G    SA/G    DIFF    SVPCT   PIM PIMA    DIFF
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(IMPORTHTML("http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/team/_/stat/scoring/year/2019/seasontype/2", 
 "table", 1))
```

[image: 0]